# The dimension of y_true is expanded by model.fit of tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The codes are as following:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class CustomData(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_data, label_data, batch_size):

        self._image_data  = np.float32((image_data / 127.5) - 1)
        self._label_data  = tf.squeeze(label_data)
        self._batch_size  = batch_size
        self._num_batches = math.ceil(image_data.shape[0] / batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._num_batches

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx1 = idx * self.batch_size
        idx2 = (idx + 1) * self.batch_size

        batch_x = self._image_data[idx1:idx2]
        batch_y = self._label_data[idx1:idx2]

        return batch_x, batch_y

    @property
    def batch_size(self):
        return self._batch_size

class SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropy(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # the rank of y_true becomes 2 and I don't know why

        #y_true = tf.cast(tf.squeeze(y_true), dtype=tf.int32)  # this line can solve the problem, but I'm just wondering why the dimension of y_true is expanded
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred))

class CustomModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super().__init__()

        self.global_avg_pool = GlobalAveragePooling2D()

        self.classifier = Dense(units=num_outputs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.global_avg_pool(inputs)
        x = self.classifier(x)

        return x

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_data = CustomData(image_data=x_train, label_data=y_train, batch_size=2)

print(train_data[0][1].shape)  # the rank of y_true is 1

model = CustomModel(num_outputs=10)

loss = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropy()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss)

model.fit(train_data)
```

The error is as following:

```
ValueError: `labels.shape.rank` must equal `logits.shape.rank - 1`. Received: labels.shape=(None, 1) of rank 2 and logits.shape=(None, 10) of rank 2
```

I knew that the error is raised in the loss function and it can be solved by tf.squeeze.
But what I don't understand is that why the dimension of y_true is expanded by model.fit. (From (batch_size,) to (batch_size, 1))
Could someone tell me why? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was performed by function match_dtype_and_rank defined in keras/keras/engine/compile_utils.py

```
def match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw):
    """Match dtype and rank of predictions."""
    if y_t.shape.rank == 1 and y_p.shape.rank == 2:
        y_t = tf.expand_dims(y_t, axis=-1)
```